# How to convert hex to float

Tags: go, floating-point, hex, type-conversion

I have to convert `hex`, represeneted as `string`s (e.g. `"0xC40C5253"`) to float values (*IEEE-754* conversion). I did not manage to do that using the strconv.ParseFloat function. Is there anything else I have to use?
I couldn't find it so far. I also tried converting it to an integer first and then to a float, but the results were wrong.

Code of my last try:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strconv"
)

func main () {
  x, err := strconv.ParseInt("C40C5253", 16, 64) 
  f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(fmt.Sprintf("%d", x), 64) 

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error in conversion: %s\n", err)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(f)
  }
}
```

Comment: I get `3.289141843e+09` from your code. Is this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First it needs to be stated the bit-length of the input. Since the hex representation has 4 bytes (8 hex digits), it is most likely a `float32` (needs clarification from the asker).

You can parse the bytes from the hex representation into an `uint32` using [`strconv.ParseUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint). `ParseUint()` always returns `uint64` which uses 8 bytes in memory so you have to convert it to `uint32` which uses 4 bytes just like `float32`:

```
s := "C40C5253"
n, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 16, 32)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
n2 = uint32(n)
```

Now you have the bytes but they are stored in a variable of type `uint32` and therefore interpreted as the bytes of an integer. And you want to interpret them as the bytes of a IEEE-754 floating point number, you can use the [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package to do that:

```
f := *(*float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&n2))
fmt.Println(f)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Cq1SCuWSPr)):

```
-561.2863
```

**Note:**

As JimB noted, for the 2nd part (translating `uint32` to `float32`) the [`math`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/) package has a built-in function [`math.Float32frombits()`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32frombits) which does exactly this under the hood:

```
f := math.Float32frombits(n2)
```

Comment: While it uses the same unsafe method, the `math` package has methods like [Float64FromBits](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64frombits) to do just this

Comment: The result has to be -561.2863 though, according to [this](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) page

Comment: @Jan The difference was because the number is a 32-bit float not 64-bit which you haven't stated. Doing so gives your expected result.

Comment: @icza what if the size of hex is representing a number of 128 bits, this code will fail at `ParseUint`

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Obviously because `uint64` is 64-bits in Go. If you have to deal with 128-bit floating point numbers, loog into [`big.Float`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float).

Answer (score 6):

Here are two different approaches that produce -561.2863: http://play.golang.org/p/Y60XB820Ib

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

func parse_read(s string) (f float32, err error) {
    b, err := hex.DecodeString(s)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    buf := bytes.NewReader(b)

    err = binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &f)

    return
}

func parse_math(s string) (f float32, err error) {
    i, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 16, 32)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    f = math.Float32frombits(uint32(i))

    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The input is 32 bits, so must be treated as a 32-bit number. It is also unsigned, so should be parsed as a uint, not int. Finally, there is no need to use unsafe operations, and in fact as used here they will fail on a machine with a different byte order.

Instead, use `math.Float32frombits`, which does exactly what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    s := "C40C5253"
    n, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 16, 32)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    nn := uint32(n)

    g := math.Float32frombits(nn)
    fmt.Println(g)
}
```

Output:

```
-561.2863
```

http://play.golang.org/p/y1ZjH9pscy

Comment: No need to editorialize about other answers. There's also no problem with byte-order, as the math package does the exact same unsafe operation of `*(*float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))`.

Comment: On [so] "previous answer" has no meaning, answers get reordered based on votes and the readers options. If you need to refer to another answer use the "share" link to get a link. Also, link only answers are not a good fit for SO, you should include the relevant part (in this case the code) from the link into the post.

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow! Instead of pasting a link to a solution, you should also add the relevant code from the link in your answer.  That way if the link ever goes down the answer is still available.